# Mongodb installation instructions

Tags: mongodb

On the Mongodb quickstart guide http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+OS+X, it says to create a /data/db directory like this

```
 $ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
 $ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

Then says to start Mongodb in one terminal using this command

```
./mongodb-xxxxxxx/bin/mongod
```

and then to start the shell in another terminal which will connect to localhost by default

```
 $ ./mongodb-xxxxxxx/bin/mongo
```

I assume "xxxxxxx" is some folder but how do I find out what folder to put in there? I'm not very skilled with Unix... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The **xxxxxxx** is just the version number of the file you downloaded.

For example if you use the Linux 64-bit version, you will download the zip file **mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz**.

Then when you unzip it (`tar xzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz`), you will get a folder called `mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2`. The `linux-x86_64-2.0.2` is what **xxxxxxx* the quickstart guide refers to.

So you do `./mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2/bin/mongod`, and `./mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2/bin/mongo`.

Answer (score -1):

on Mac OS X.10.5.8 here are the simple steps, using macports.

i had to remove my boost package and use the 1.49 version instead.

Here are the commands sequence I used:

```
$sudo port -v selfupdate
$svn co  -r 93341 'http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/devel/boost/'
$cd /tmp
$cd boost/
$sudo port install boost
$sudo port activate boost @1.49.0_0
$sudo port install mongodb
```

an then time to run mongo:

```
$sudo port load mongodb
$mongo localhost/admin
>
```

.